# jQuery CSS doesn't trigger correctly on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm having problems on mobile Cordova with a very simple function that first sets a width/height for an element and then it works on the span inside the element (big text plugin - not related to this plugin though)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".blockstart").each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            "width": blockwidth,
            "height": blockwidth
        });
        alert("css change");
    });
    $(".blockstart").find("span").bigText();
</script>
```

**What is happening:**

1. Css alerts for each blockstart element (although no visible changes on page).
2. Work is done on the span element but not right because parent element doesn't have a set with/height.
3. Only now the width/height of the parent(blockstart) changes.

This only happens on **mobile**. This is driving me crazy, any suggestions please?

---

I've even tried the following function which works but not all the time (on mobile).

```
          function runbigtext(div) {
              var initbigtext = setInterval(function() {
                  if ($("" + div + "[style*='height']").length == $(div).length) {
                      clearInterval(initbigtext);
                      $(div).find("span").bigText();
                  }
              }, 50);
          }
          runbigtext(".blockstart");
```

This sometimes works, sometimes it does not (To work properly, the div.blockstart should have a width and height set and be visible in the page with these sizes. The bigtext function works by making the span text element inside fit the size of the parent div.). This only happens on mobile.

I can't explain what is happening.

Comment: Unrelated to what you're asking about, do you know you don't need the each loop? If you're applying the same width and height to all of the elements you can call `.css()` directly on `$(".blockstart")`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple solution, by adding delay to your work to give time for all your css styling done before your work starts

```
$(".blockstart").find("span").delay(1000).bigText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove alert , u may use console instead , 
And call function inside the each loop passing $this as the parameter , so if due to slow rendering the async process doesn't overlap this

Just call the function inside each loop and change the css there ,